# Como construir séries temporais com frequências diferentes da original?

Tags: python, r, séries-temporais

Tenho um dataframe com dados de precipitação diária, com datas de 01/01/1900 até 31/12/2010, exemplo:

```
# Data             Est_1      Est_2      Est_3   
# 17/12/2010          NA          0          0   
# 18/12/2010          NA          0          0    
# 19/12/2010          NA        1.7          0     
# 20/12/2010          NA        1.1       37.2    
# 21/12/2010          NA       88.5         50   
# 22/12/2010          NA        30           0
```

Quero extrair algumas informações deste dataframe, como sub-séries contendo a informação:

- a mínima precipitação diária anual
- a média precipitação diária anual
- a máxima precipitação diária anual

Como fazer isto no R ou no Python?

Comment: O R possui várias funções nativas para se trabalhar com séries temporais, baseadas nos objetos `ts`. Existem também vários pacotes extras, como `zoo` e `timeSeries`. Você já tentou utilizar algum deles? Do jeito que sua pergunta foi feita, a resposta é simplesmente "Sim, em R, existe".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em R, você pode utilizar o pacote `lubridate` que facilitará muito a manipulação de datas, em conjunto com o `dplyr`.

Veja um exemplo:

```
library(lubridate)

dados <- data.frame(
  data = seq(dmy('01/01/1900'),dmy('31/12/2010'), by = '1 day'),
  valor = 1:40542
  )
```

Calculando as medidas por **ano**:

```
> library(dplyr)
> dados %>% 
+   group_by(year(data)) %>% 
+   summarise(media = mean(valor), minimo = min(valor), maximo = max(valor))
Source: local data frame [111 x 4]

   year(data)  media minimo maximo
1        1900  183.0      1    365
2        1901  548.0    366    730
3        1902  913.0    731   1095
4        1903 1278.0   1096   1460
5        1904 1643.5   1461   1826
6        1905 2009.0   1827   2191
7        1906 2374.0   2192   2556
8        1907 2739.0   2557   2921
9        1908 3104.5   2922   3287
10       1909 3470.0   3288   3652
..        ...    ...    ...    ...
```

Calculando por **mês do ano**:

```
> dados %>% group_by(year(data), month(data)) %>% 
+   summarise(media = mean(valor), min = min(valor), maximo = max(valor))
Source: local data frame [1,332 x 5]
Groups: year(data)

   year(data) month(data) media min maximo
1        1900           1  16.0   1     31
2        1900           2  45.5  32     59
3        1900           3  75.0  60     90
4        1900           4 105.5  91    120
5        1900           5 136.0 121    151
6        1900           6 166.5 152    181
7        1900           7 197.0 182    212
8        1900           8 228.0 213    243
9        1900           9 258.5 244    273
10       1900          10 289.0 274    304
..        ...         ...   ... ...    ...
```

Veja todos os elementos de uma data que você pode extrair:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste link tem uma explicação detalhada do lubridate: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/paper

Comment: Obrigado Daniel!

Comment: Fiquei com uma duvida sobre o resultado. Considerando que são várias estações de medições, ou seja, várias medidas para o mesmo dia, a média, o mínimo e máximo de cada dia, são de cada estação ou de todas as estações para aquele dia?

Comment: As médias são referentes apenas a uma coluna, no meu exemplo ela está com o nome "valor". Você poderia calcular as medidas para cada estação separadamente substituindo o nome "valor" por "Est_1", "Est2", etc. Ou, pode calcular para todas, criando alguma coluna base que agregue os valores das três estações. Por exemplo `dados$media3est <-  rowMeans(dados[,c("Est_1", "Est_2", "Est_3)], na.rm = T)` e depois usar "media3est" no lugar de "valor".

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 2):

Ou se você preferir o pacote data.table e um pouco de regex :)

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

dTbl = data.table(data=seq(dmy('01/01/1900'),
                           dmy('31/12/2010'),
                           by='1 day'),
                  valor=1:40542)

dTbl[, year := str_extract(data, perl('^[0-9]+(?=-)'))]
dTbl[, month := str_extract(data, perl('(?<=-)[0-9]+(?=-)'))]

dTbl[, .(median=median(as.numeric(valor)),
         mean=mean(valor),
         min=min(valor),
         max=max(valor)), by=year]

dTbl[, .(median=median(as.numeric(valor)),
         mean=mean(valor),
         min=min(valor),
         max=max(valor)), by=.(year, month)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Python você pode utilizar o pacote "Pandas" para manipulação de dataframes.

Neste caso, sugiro fazer os agrupamentos por ano e depois pegar as informações que você precisa.

Para mais exemplos e referência, veja o link:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html